Berserker—quick Crusader variant
Note: Feedback on this question has led to another iteration. This is for your information; you are still welcome to answer this question and your feedback will be considered.
Looking for a review of a quick variant crusader, the berserker. Goal is to balance with the crusader itself.

Crusader Variant: Berserker
Many believe berserkers’ fits of rage to be divine blessings—or curses. Even more than crusaders, berserkers follow the whims of fate and are only empowered by dire circumstance.
Alignment: Any nonlawful, including true neutral.
Class Features
As a crusader of your level, except you do not gain furious counterstrike, indomitable soul, zealous surge, or smite, and Devoted Spirit and White Raven are not berserker disciplines. Instead, you gain the following:
Disciplines: Iron Heart, Stone Dragon, and Tiger Claw.
Berserker Strength (Ex): As the alternate barbarian class feature from Player’s Handbook II, except the activation threshold is based on initiator level (the upgrades at 11th and 20th are still based on class level).
Steely Resolve (Ex): As crusader, except that the size of the delayed damage pool additionally increases by 5 at 2nd and every four levels thereafter (6th, 10th, 14th, 18th), for a total of steely resolve 60 at 20th.
Damage delayed by steely resolve counts towards whether or not berserker strength activates (effectively, while steely resolve delays taking the damage, it does not delay activating berserker strength).


You might want to consider changing Berserker Strength to trigger at 4 x character level, to a) compensate for the smaller hit dice of the Crusader and b) allow for prestige classes, which Berserker Strength doesn't.

@From I changed it to 5 × initiator level; that allows some prestige classes (and the remainder are far less painful and can be mitigated with Chaos Rage). I think 5 is still appropriate; a d10 and a d12 are not that different (d12 is 18% bigger than d10 but 5 is 25% larger than 4—a difference in ratio of almost 50%), plus from experience, 5 × level is too low, really.

Before properly analyzing the balance, I think it important to note some secondary concerns that are unrelated to balance.
First, I think a modified skill list would make sense from a flavor perspective.  The two Knowledge skills stand out in that respect - I think replacing them with Survival and Tumble would make the most sense.  Survival would make sense for a Barbarian style class, and Tumble would synergize well with the increased mobility from Tiger Claw.
Second, I'm noticing that there is no mental stat synergy.  Everything requiring Charisma is gone, and the three disciplines on offer all key off of Strength and Dexterity.  While there's nothing inherently wrong with this, and the Berserker is clearly built to be a big dumb brute, I think the way the Tome of Battle encourages martial characters to use their mental stats is one of the more underrated achievements of the book.  Some built-in synergy with Survival or Intimidate would fit the flavor without being too centralizing.
Anyway, as for the balance itself...
Perhaps stronger at low levels, but definitely weaker later on.
Low Levels
At very low levels, I don't think you'll be especially likely to trigger Berserker Strength very often.  Often by the time an enemy rolls well enough to hit a meaningful attack, the fight is already half-over.  That's okay, though, since you've still got the vast majority of what makes a low-level Crusader so powerful, plus the added power of things like Wall of Blades and Sudden Leap.  Nothing the Berserker gives up is really all that important to a low-level Crusader, since Indomitable Soul and Zealous Surge don't see a lot of use until mid levels.
So, at low levels, I think there's a slight edge to the Berserker thanks to Tiger Claw having such exceptional low level stuff.  There is a much greater advantage in the specific case of a glass cannon build - I could see a Wood Elf using the elven penalty to Con to live in a near-constant state of rage, for instance.  This build would fall off hard at later levels, of course, but it could be viable enough to warrant some kind of clause stating that Berserker Strength can't kick in at full HP.
Mid Levels
At this point, Steely Resolve is really starting to catch up and give the Berserker the temporary survivability needed to make the most of Berserker Strength.  Unfortunately, this is also when in-combat healing is really falling off.  Packing 25 damage in a delayed damage pool is a lot more dangerous when there's no way to heal yourself, too.  Level 11 is a godsend for this class in that respect, as it's both when Berserker Strength levels up and when the party healer learns Heal.
This is around the point where you're going to really start missing Indomitable Soul and Zealous Surge, though.  The bonus on saves from Berserker Strength certainly helps, but it doesn't do nearly enough to cover the loss fully.  While Iron Heart Surge lends a hand with this problem, the Crusader's random maneuver selection holds it back a lot.
It's not all bad, of course.  Tiger Claw is giving a lot of useful battlefield mobility, and the fact that so many Tiger Claw maneuvers have overlapping functions is actually incredibly useful in the context of the Crusader's randomness.  The class is also giving some incredibly serious damage output when things line up right.  I would not personally find this a suitable upside for the marked loss in defenses, but that's entirely a matter of opinion at this point.
High Levels
This is where spells are really flying and damage has crossed the threshold of "anything less than 3 digits may as well be a peashooter."  That said, the berserker is definitely keeping up on damage.  High levels are surely going to give many ways to cheese the Berserker into a perpetually low health pool to boot.
However, even if we assume perpetual rage, this class has had to give up a lot of utility, and it's going to be felt here.  This class gives up the opportunity to double-dip Charisma into will saves, gives up a safety net of rerolls against domination spells, foregoes the potent team synergy of White Raven and Devoted Spirit, and locks itself completely into the role of face-smasher by relying on rage.
Yes, it smashes lots of face.  But, at high levels, that's a really low bar to clear.  Yeah, it's very mobile, but that's also an expected thing at this point.  Sure, it has a ton of damage deferrence, but any monster that can't break past that anyway is probably capable of exploiting the Berserker's more notable weakness to save-based effects.
In short, a lot of what gives martial adepts viability at high levels is how well-rounded they are.  The Berserker, while plenty strong, rejects well-roundedness in the pursuit of smashing more face.  At high levels, this falls apart.  While it isn't a bad class by any means, even at high level (a barbarian would give an arm and a leg to do what this class is doing), it will likely fall short of the high standards set by the base Crusader.
As a dip
I mean, it's a Crusader variant, of course it's good for dipping, but I think this is a significantly better dip than the base Crusader.  Having another strong class feature open from level 1 that keys off of initiator level doubles down on what makes initiators so dippable to begin with.
More specifically, this also makes the class remarkably good at blending with other initiators.  Being able to trade a Warblade's or Swordsage's capstone for this Berserker Strength progression is a really potent option that greatly outclasses taking more levels in Berserker.  This is especially true on the lower-health Swordsage.
The problem reminds me a lot of the issues with the Wizard class, actually.  While Wizard is a ludicrously powerful class, nobody takes Wizard 20 because there are prestige classes that grant all of the spellcasting while also giving real class features.  The same is true of this Berserker: the lack of strong class features will encourage players to leave early.
Addendum: Suggestions
I really like this variant.  The idea of grafting the Barbarian onto the Crusader's frame is a good one, and Berserker Strength is an inspired way to do it.  As mentioned, I think the class suffers from a lack of well-roundedness at mid and high levels, so since this variant class inspired me, here are some ideas of the kinds of abilities that could fill the gaps.
These are, of course, rough suggestions, and using all of them would be overkill.  They simply give an idea of the kinds of things I think would do well on the class to bring it back up to the Crusader's level.
Feral Determination
The thrill of carnage grants you an unstoppable willpower.  Whenever you drop a hostile creature, you gain a +1 morale bonus to all saving throws.  This bonus increases by 1 for each creature you drop, but it cannot exceed one-half your Berserker level.  This bonus goes away at the end of your turn if you have not dropped a creature since the end of your last turn.
Fear of Retribution
Beginning at 6th level, your fearsome demeanor can cause your opponents to second-guess their attacks at a crucial moment.  Whenever you are the target of a single target spell or ability that forces you to make a saving throw, you may glare down the opponent targeting you as an immediate action.  You roll an Intimidate check against the opponent as if perfomring the Demoralize action.  On a success, the opponent's ability fails and the opponent is Shaken until the beginning of his next turn.  On a failure, you automatically fail the saving throw for the spell or ability.
You may use this ability once per day.  At 18th level, you may use this ability one addtional time per day.
Too Angry to Die
Your untoppable displays of rage have become so legendary that even death has learned to tread carefully in your presence.  At 20th level, if you are affected by petrification or a death effect, it does not apply to you until the end of your next turn.  If you would be cured of the delayed effect or made immune to it, such as by a Stone to Flesh spell for petrification or a Death Ward spell for a death effect, the effect is prevented.
Additionally, while such an effect is being delayed, you gain the benefits of Berserker Strength as though your hit points had been reduced.
Other class features
Any of Evasion, Uncanny Dodge, Track, Fast Movement, or Elude Touch (as a Wilder) would be good options.

I see the Berserker as less "smash face" and more "brick wall", what with all the damage deferral. I also imagine Stone Power to be a key part of many low-level builds based on the Berserker chassis. +1, anyway - great write-up.

Skills: pure oversight, great call. Mental scores: eh, with the way 3.5e handles abilities, I don’t think Tome of Battle succeeds here as well as you seem to, and don’t miss it much. Well-roundedness: a good point, certainly, will give thought. As for your suggestions, great, and I love fear of retribution in particular.

@From The reason I give less attention to the tankiness angle is that the extremely high deferred damage pool shows some diminishing returns.  By the time it starts getting really big, there are a lot of ways to just straight-up bypass it through immobilizing conditions and ability damage.

@PhoenixDuck That’s a fantastic point, and it’s well worth considering options to delay other things. That might go really far towards both ensuring we can enable berserker strength reliably enough, and also allow the berserker to do its job in the face of the usual save-or-suck-based combat of 3.5e.

One thing that may be unclear: multiclass martial adepts have separate initiator levels for both classes, and the berserker strength activation threshold is based on one’s berserker initiator level. Being a 19th-level warblade/1st-level berserker gives you a berserker IL of 10th, i.e. 55 hp (counting steely resolve), which is not that great. Initiating prestige classes count towards both classes, though, so a 4th-level warblade/1st-level berserker/5th-level bloodclaw master/10th-level eternal blade (or whatever) is in a much better place, with berserker IL 18th and a 95-hp threshold.

@KRyan I was unaware of that multiclassing interaction.  While I still maintain that a Berserker dip would be noticably better than a Crusader dip in most cases, that certainly tones down the specific case of using it to beef up a Swordsage.

Disciplines
The whole combination of Stone Dragon / Iron Heart / Tiger Claw is a subset of the Disciplines available to the Warblade.
According to this Warblade handbook, the Stone Dragon you keep is the least useful Warblade Discipline, and consequently the least useful of the Berserker's. Easy prerequisites, though.
The Tiger Claw isn't as easy on the prerequisites, though, so will demand a bit more of any build involving it. It can provide some mobility, which is always nice.
That mobility is nicely complimented by the Iron Heart Surge, and Iron Heart on the whole is pretty great at keeping you in the fight.
For these, you trade away the party-oriented Disciplines of Devoted Spirit and White Raven.
Verdict: The Berserker's Disciplines are less focused on the party than on himself, and even though Iron Heart somewhat makes up for Devoted Spirit, it still doesn't give the same staying power. Altogether, a downgrade, even if the Crusader chassi's superior recovery mechanic might open up for some potential uses of TC/IH I haven't seen in games.
Steely Resolve
Verdict: A strict upgrade, albeit not a very large one. Helps offset the decreased staying power. Notably, does NOT improve with Initiator Level.
The Trade
Indomitable Soul helped a lot with your Will save, but not having it (nor Smite) will decrease your MAD somewhat. Steadfast Determination will probably be a good investment and will pair great with Mettle.
Lack of Zealous Surge will still hurt, though.
A version of Berserker Strength which DOES improve with Initiator Level is only activated when you have taken enough damage.
Your delayed damage from Steely Resolve, combined with a good enough party healer, can allow you to keep your hp just below the necessary activation point after the first round of combat, seeing as you can choose to heal delayed damage before actual damage.
If so, you will generally fight with a +4 bonus to your Strength score, a +2 bonus on saves, damage reduction 2/-, and a -2 penalty to your AC, increased by 50% at level 11 and another 50% (for 100% total) at level 20.
Verdict: Slightly less MAD, with worse Saves and no Smite, for a potential bonus which isn't bad, but which isn't that good, neither. A sidegrade at best, a downgrade at worst.
Overall Balance
I would have to actually playtest this to figure out if there are any exploits available for having Crusader recovery with Iron Heart and/or Tiger Claw. Barring that, I see little upsides to this class compared to a Crusader with a single level dip into Barbarian, if Berserker Strength is really that interesting.
Even more playtesting would be required to see what can be achieved when combined with other classes. It would be very helpful to see a build based on the class, with some notes on specific interactions.
Until I have seen that in practice, I would consider the class as a whole a downgrade to the Crusader for regular party play, but possibly an upgrade for solo play.
Suggested Changes
Let the Berserker keep Devoted Spirit, which is the only Crusader-specific Discipline in the first place. It makes the class less dependent on a party healer's devoted attention. If you want to keep the class at three, trade away Tiger Claw instead, unless you have some plans for it.
Make Steadfast Determination a free bonus feat on level 3, to replace Indomitable Soul now that much of the Charisma-related features are removed.
Change the Alignment prerequisite to "Any nonlawful, except true neutral", to better reflect the renewed focus on devotion / determination (which any variant of Crusader should have).

Excellent analysis—it somehow slipped my mind that the disciplines were a strict subset of warblade disciplines. I considered leaving Devoted Spirit in, increasing the discipline count, and that seems more appropriate now in light of this analysis. Steadfast Determination is indeed an excellent feat here, and quite possibly worth including as a bonus feat. All that said, I have to apologize—I should have edited this question to note that I already have a take 2. Not that this analysis isn’t useful—it very much is! But I hope you don’t feel misled.

No worries, I started writing this when I originally commented on your question, then forgot all about it for way too long. My bad!
